# CocoaPods for iOS : use System Ruby Gem or User Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

As far as I know, there are 2 Ruby in my Mac OS X , the System Ruby Gem and User Ruby Gem.

Both have version `2.1.5` ( confirmed by `sudo gem --version` and `gem --version` ). I use System Ruby Gem to install CocoaPods:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and the installed version is `0.25.0`. Use Ruby Gem did not install CocoaPods. Am I doing right to develop iOS Apps, with libraries managed by `cocoapods` ? or should I use `gem install cocoapods` to install with User Ruby Gem ?

I'm little confused here.

Output of `which -a gem`:

```
/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem
/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/bin/gem
/usr/bin/gem
```

Comment: Does `which -a gem` return multiple lines?

Comment: 3 lines returned. See updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I would say you want to use `gem install cocoapods` but regardless of whether or not you add `sudo` it's still pointing to the same gem. Which is the `/Users/MyUserName/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem` since it is the first returned from `which -a` it is the first in your `$PATH`. Part of the purpose of using a ruby version manager such as RVM or rbenv is so you don't have to use `sudo` to install ruby gems. This way they can be entirely owned and manage wit your own user's permissions. So in this case when you use `gem install cocoapods` it's installing locally with RVM (somewhere in `~/.rvm` and with the correct user permissions instead of root permissions.

Comment: Therefore, should I uninstall cocoapods with sudo and install it without sudo ?

Comment: You could, I'm not actually sure if the permissions differ, you could dive into `~/.rvm` and see with `ls -l` if you wanted to. Otherwise next time you run `gem update` without `sudo` and there's a new version of CocoaPods it will install it normally.

Comment: `gem update` does not include `cocoapods`. Last, I uninstalled sudo copy of cocoapods & install a non-sudo one. Problem solved.